# "have to?" in question tag

Tags: semi-modals, tag-questions

How can I use "have to" in question tags? Which one is correct? Can I say it both ways?

> He has to come alone, doesn’t he?

or

> He has to come alone, hasn’t he?

Comment: What do you mean by "question tag"?

Comment: @Lawrence I think they mean a [tag question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_question).

Comment: To my (AmE) ear, "doesn't he" sounds more correct, but I'll leave it to someone who knows the grammatical reason for that to write a proper answer. I wouldn't be surprised if the second version is acceptable in BrE.

Comment: The negative form for *have to* is *don't have to* (in the same fashion for the third person). Hence, if we want to use the question tag, we use *doesn't he?* If it was *hasn't he*, we'd be sticking with the present perfect form as a question tag.

Answer (score 1):

In OP's example (where ***he has to*** means ***he must***) it's *not* valid to use ***has he?*** as a "question tag".

That's because ***has*** in the preceding statement is a special usage that's effectively a completely different word to normal usages. It's even pronounced differently: not only is it *always* stressed - most native speakers normally enunciate it as ***hass*** (with an '**s**', not a '**z**'). And ***hass he?*** is a completely unidiomatic question tag.

In other contexts, such as *He has ten fingers, hasn't he?*, it's fine to repeat the "statement verb" in the question tag, but even there I suspect most native speakers today would probably use ***does he?***.

Answer (score 0):

You use the former. The latter stands for an answer involving the present perfect form.

> He has to come alone, *doesn't he?* (*doesn't he have to come alone?*)

This sticks with the negative form of the *have to* which in this case is the third person.

> He has to come alone, *hasn't he?*

This question tag works when invoking the present perfect form:

> He **has come** alone, *hasn't he?*